# Userfaultfd fails register with ENOMEM after execv

Tags: rust, execv

I have a program (`parent.rs`) that will:

- Fork
- Create a `userfaultfd` on the child, then transfer it to the parent (with `pidfd_getfd`).
- Execs the child (`child.rs`)
- Child allocates memory with `mmap` and "sends" it to the parent
- Parent receives the memory pointer and tries to register it with the transferred `userfaultfd` object

Unfortunately this fails at the last step with `ENOMEM`.

I'm aware that, due to virtual memory, the child pointer will *not* be valid on the parent. But I expect it to be valid to the `userfaultfd` handle I have, since it was originally created on the parent and, due to not having `O_CLOEXEC`, should remain open afterwards (and I've verified this by reading `/proc/{child_pid}/fd`).

Cargo.toml:

```ini
[package]
name = "..."
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
nix = "0.26.2"
pidfd = "0.2.4"
pidfd_getfd = { version = "0.2.1", features = ["nightly"] }
pipe-channel = "1.3.0"
rustix = { version = "0.37.3", features = ["mm"] }
userfaultfd = { version = "0.5.1", features = ["linux4_14", "linux5_7"] }
```

examples/parent.rs:

```rust
use {
    nix::unistd,
    rustix::fd::{AsRawFd, FromRawFd},
    std::{
        ffi::{self, CString},
        mem,
    },
    userfaultfd::Uffd,
};

fn main() {
    let child_name = std::env::args().nth(1).expect("Expected argument");

    // Fork and execute the child
    let (mut uffd_tx, mut uffd_rx) = pipe_channel::channel();
    let (mut ready_tx, mut ready_rx) = pipe_channel::channel();
    let child_pid = match unsafe { unistd::fork() }.expect("Unable to fork") {
        unistd::ForkResult::Parent { child } => child,
        unistd::ForkResult::Child => {
            // Open the uffd and send it to the parent
            // Note: We forget it so it doesn't get closed.
            let uffd = userfaultfd::UffdBuilder::new()
                .close_on_exec(false)
                .user_mode_only(true)
                .non_blocking(false)
                .create()
                .expect("Unable to create uffd");
            uffd_tx.send(uffd.as_raw_fd()).expect("Unable to send uffd");
            mem::forget(uffd);

            // Wait until the monitor process is ready
            ready_rx.recv().expect("Unable to wait for parent");

            // Then execute the child
            println!("Executing child");
            let path = CString::new(child_name.clone()).unwrap();
            let args = [CString::new(child_name).unwrap()];
            unistd::execv(&path, &args).expect("Unable to `execv`");

            unreachable!();
        },
    };

    // Open a pid_fd for the child process
    let child_pidfd =
        unsafe { pidfd::PidFd::open(child_pid.as_raw(), 0) }.expect("Unable to allocate pidfd for child process");

    // Receive the uffd from the child
    let child_uffd_fd = uffd_rx.recv().expect("Unable to receive uffd");
    let uffd_fd = unsafe { pidfd_getfd::pidfd_getfd(child_pidfd.as_raw_fd(), child_uffd_fd, 0) };
    let uffd = unsafe { Uffd::from_raw_fd(uffd_fd) };

    // Tell the child we're ready to execute
    ready_tx.send(()).expect("Unable to send parent event");

    // Then read the pointer it wrote
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));
    let page = std::fs::read("ptr").expect("Unable to read pointer");
    let page = page.try_into().expect("File wasn't the right size");
    let page = usize::from_le_bytes(page);
    let page = page as *mut ffi::c_void;

    // Prove the pointer is on the process's maps
    let memory_map =
        std::fs::read_to_string(format!("/proc/{}/maps", child_pid.as_raw())).expect("Unable to read memory maps");
    assert!(memory_map.contains(&format!("{:x}", page as usize)));

    // Then try to register
    uffd.register(page, 4096).expect("Unable to register dummy pointer");
}
```

examples/child.rs:

```
use {rustix::mm, std::ptr};

pub fn main() {
    // Allocate the page
    println!("Child: Allocating");
    let page = unsafe {
        mm::mmap_anonymous(
            ptr::null_mut(),
            4096,
            mm::ProtFlags::READ | mm::ProtFlags::WRITE,
            mm::MapFlags::PRIVATE,
        )
        .expect("Unable to allocate page")
    };

    // Write to file
    println!("Child: Writing to file");
    std::fs::write("ptr", (page as usize).to_le_bytes()).expect("Unable to write");

    println!("Child: Sleeping");
    loop {
        std::thread::park();
    }
}
```

This is run with `cargo build --examples && ./target/debug/examples/parent ./target/debug/examples/child`

(Note the `uffd` handler isn't here, but even with it it doesn't work, I removed it to create a smaller mvcp).

**How can I make `userfaultfd` actually work here and register on the child?**

If it helps, I'm using `ptrace` in my actual application, so I can control the child much more easily, if I need to do it at a specific time.

I have currently found a very hacky workaround using `LD_PRELOAD`, by creating the uffd object after `execve` on a shared library loaded by `LD_PRELOAD`, then transfering it to the parent with pipes (whose fds are given to the library by environment variables). This unfortunately is not great because:

- <s>I need to use the non-usermode + fork features of uffd, which requires the `cap_sys_ptrace` capability. In turn this capability disables the ability to `LD_PRELOAD`. I've heard that if the library has the setuid bit and is owned by root, it should still work, but I haven't been able to get it working.</s> I've managed to fix this by setting the `cap_sys_ptrace` capability on the parent, then raising the `Inheritable` and `Ambient` capability sets of `cap_sys_ptrace` (still on the parent). This preserves the capability after `execv`, without disabling the ability to load a `LD_PRELOAD` library.
- It delays the creation of the uffd. In my use case, I'm interested in tracking allocations, and some do happen before `LD_PRELOAD` initialization. This isn't a major issue, but it does complicate the design of the program, as now we need to go back and check all allocations that happened before the uufd was loaded.
- It's a very hacky and unsecure method, which could easily break and/or have security vulnerabilities.